# maven exec:java run class file within jar

Tags: maven

I have my code packaged into a jar

The jar is packaged ok.

```
jar -tfv target/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

com/
com/codevalid/
com/codevalid/App.class
log4j.xml
META-INF/maven/com.codevalid/test/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.codevalid/test/pom.properties
```

I can execute them when they are present as individual class files using `exec:java`

How to run class file within jar using maven `exec:java`?

Comment: Sorry,  How to run class file within jar using maven exec:java

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337857/mvn-execjava-to-run-a-java-file-in-an-external-jar-file

Answer (score 7):

Ok, this is what i finally ended up doing.
I built the jar using

```
mvn assembly:single
```

and used

```
java -jar ./target/App-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.codevalid.App
```

I did see an alternative where i could have used

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.codevalid.App"
```

But i was not sure how pass the name of the **jar as a classpath**

Answer (score 5):

You can run a jar file using the `exec:java` goal by adding some `arguments`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-jar</argument>
            <argument>target/myJar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you have an executable jar and don't want to define the entry point, you need to set the `executable` and use the `exec:exec` goal:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-jar</argument>
            <argument>target/myJar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What if I want to pass some arguments to the main method of the `org.example.Main` class ?

Comment: @prime I 'm haven't tested it but I think you can use [`<commandlineArgs>`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#commandlineArgs) to pass arguments to the actual application

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will check that. Anyway got an answer to the actual problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337857/mvn-execjava-to-run-a-java-file-in-an-external-jar-file

Answer (score 3):

You need to include your jar file as a dependency to the exec plugin, e.g. like this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>install</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>java</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>com.codevalid.App</mainClass>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can skip the `dependency` declaration if the `com.codevalid.App` class is compiled as part of your current project.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info, but this seems to work only if the jar in the repository. What i wanted to do is to test the jar, before i can install it in the repo. Is there any way where I can specify the **location of this jar** to  maven exec:java

Comment: @codevalid, @nwinkler's answer should be sufficient for your purposes because running `mvn install` on your dependent project in your local environment will put it in your local .m2 repository.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify *classpathScope* and *includePluginDependencies* or *includeProjectDependencies* parameters to pickup jar files on the classpath.

Here is an example:

```
           <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <mainClass>com.google.jstestdriver.JsTestDriver</mainClass>
                <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                <commandlineArgs>--port 9876</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>
```