# mvn exec:java to run a java file in an external JAR file

Tags: java, maven-exec-plugin

In the pom.xml there is a usage of `maven-dependency-plugin` to download a specific external JAR file to a separate location (in /tmp/externalTestJars/testjar.jar).

And I want to use `exec-maven-plugin` to run a java class in the **testjar.jar** file (Main.java).

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924994/maven-execjava-run-class-file-within-jar) asking kinda same question but the answer for that question did not help me.

If I directly run the Main.java file (in the original project where the .jar got created, using `mvn exec:java`) I can use the below pom configuration.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
<configuration>
    <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
    <!-- need to pass two arguments to the Main.java file main method -->
    <arguments>
        <argument>arg one</argument>
        <argument>arg two</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

In the above SO question it has an answer like below to run a java file inside a .jar file.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
<configuration>
    <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
    <arguments>
        <argument>-jar</argument>
        <argument>/tmp/externalTestJars/testjar.jar</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

But in my case those arguments will be considered as the one to pass for the main method in Main.java sine it is expecting two arguments. So that approach didn't work for me.

Can this be done using exec maven plugin or is there any other method to do the same.

Comment: This might also help if the .jar download location doesn't matter for the plugin. So that we can add that as a plugin dependency. http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run the class similar to `java -cp /tmp/externalTestJars/testjar.jar org.example.Main` the plugin should be configured as below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-cp</argument>
            <argument>/tmp/externalTestJars/testjar.jar</argument>
            <argument>org.example.Main</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you want to run the class similar to `java -jar /tmp/externalTestJars/testjar.jar` (assuming `org.example.Main` is defined as `Main-Class` in the `MANIFEST.MF`) the plugin should be configured as below.

```
<configuration>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>
        <argument>-jar</argument>
        <argument>/tmp/externalTestJars/testjar.jar</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
```

In both cases run it with `mvn exec:exec`

**edit:** An example for using `mvn exec:java`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
        <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>
                /tmp/externalTestJars/testjar.jar
            </additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**note:** If the project and the jar file `testjar.jar` both contain the class `org.example.Main` then the class from the project will be executed. As the classpath elements defined by `additionalClasspathElement` will be appended to the projects classpath.

Comment: Great (Y) This seems like the solution for the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Btw can we achieve this for mvn exec:java , so that we can set the Main class in the pom.

Comment: @prime Have a look at the example for `exec:java`.

Comment: great. About your note regarding having the same class in project and .jar I did found this though.
http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html

Comment: @prime It depends what you want to achieve. In your question you told about an external Jar file which is in no kind part of the project. The link in your comment speaks about a Maven managed dependency.